# Left-side wrapfigures and marginnotes

Tags: wrapfigure, marginnote

A wrapfigure on the left side of the page interferes with the mechanism that `marginnote` uses to determine horizontal position, pushing it to the right by the width of the wrapfigure.

The `marginnote` package has the macros `\marginnoteleftadjust` and `\marginnoterightadjust` for custom horizontal adjustment, but I haven't had any luck getting these to move the notes at all.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[8]{L}{3cm}
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-grid-100x100pt} 
\end{wrapfigure}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum
\marginnote{This margin note is too far right}
\lipsum[1-2]
\marginnote{This one is not too far right}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the outer \parshape is used inside the marginnote too and so the first line of the margin note are indented like the lines of your paragraph. 
`marginnote` imho should better use \parbox instead of the primitive `\vbox` then the code from wrapfig which tries to avoid this side effects would have a chance. You can try this patch:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}
\usepackage{xpatch}


\makeatletter %two replacements!
\patchcmd\@mn@@@marginnote{\hsize\marginparwidth}{\@parboxrestore\hsize=\marginparwidth}{}{\fail}
\patchcmd\@mn@@@marginnote{\hsize\marginparwidth}{\@parboxrestore\hsize=\marginparwidth}{}{\fail}
\makeatother


\begin{document}


\begin{wrapfigure}[8]{L}{3cm}
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}
\end{wrapfigure}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum\marginnote{This margin note is too far right} 

\lipsum[1-2]
\marginnote{This one is not too far right}
\lipsum[3] 
\end{document}
```